# free stress boundary condition

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, boundary-conditions, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

I would like to understand better the free stress boundary condition. Indeed, force equilibrium writes $\nabla.\sigma=0$, and not $\sigma=0$, so which basic physical principle (such as force equilibrium, minimization of the energy, of the energy dissipation, attractive stationnary states...) is supposed to give that condition ?

Besides, that, how could I obtain a typical time for the relaxation of a system that would not respect that condition towards a state that would respect it.

thx

Comment: If it is any help, $\nabla\cdot\sigma$ gives the force per unit volume due to stresses at a point, so that's the quantity that appears in a force balance on a small elemental volume of a body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary condition at such a surface is ***not*** that the stress tensor is equal to zero.  It is that the stress tensor dotted with a unit normal to the surface (the so-called surface traction vector) is equal to zero (or more precisely, the traction vector is equal to minus the surrounding atmospheric pressure times the normal).  This is just an acknowledgment of what we know to be actual loading imposed on the surface (namely no loading over and above that of atmospheric pressure).

This all applies to the case of a solid.  In the case of a liquid, surface tension needs to be taken into consideration if the interface is curved.

Comment: Thx. What do u mean by "dotted" ? And in the case when stresses exist but compensate, is there a physical idea behind the assumption ?

Comment: What do you think of that : when we look at a surface which is the interface, the force exerted on it writes $\sigma.\overline{n}dS$. Assuming equilibrium of forces implies that $\sigma .\overline{n}=0$.

Comment: It's basically taking the matrix product of the stress matrix and the column vector representing the unit normal to the surface.  See the section entitled Cauchy's Law in this link:  http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_3_Stress_Mass_Momentum/Stress_Balance_Principles_03_The_Cauchy_Stress_Tensor.pdf

Comment: Concerning your previous comment, I agree.  I guess that, if you were doing a force balance on a small section of the (massless) interface, it could be regarded as a balance of forces.